# How do I have my out put for my form show up all together on the same line instead of spaced apart?

Tags: php, html, forms, output

I need my form out put to generate like the following example instead of being all spaced out EX. Hi _______, how are you doing this ______? 
    Hope you have a wonderful time _____________.  please help! Im new to programming!

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Test1-1</title>
        </head>
        <body>
    <?php
    if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "userName")){
    // the form exists, so work with it
    $userName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "userName");
    print "<h2>Hi $userName</h2>";
    }

    if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "morning")){
        filter_input(INPUT_POST, "morning");
        print"<h2>how are you doing this morning?</h2>";
    }
    if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "afternoon")){
        print"<h2>how are you doing this afternoon?</h2>";
        filter_input(INPUT_GET, "afternoon");
    }
    if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "evening")){
        print"<h2>how are you doing this evening?</h2>";
        filter_input(INPUT_POST, "evening");
    }
    if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "plan")){
        $plan = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "plan");
        print "<h2>Hope you have a wonderful time $plan</h2>";
    }
    //there's no input. Create the form 
    print <<< HERE

    <form action ="" method = "post">
    <fieldset>
    <label>Please enter your name</label> 
    <input type = "text"
             name = "userName"/><br>
    <label>Time of Day</label>
    <input type = "checkbox"
            name = "morning"/>
            <label>Morning</label>
    <input type = "checkbox"
            name = "afternoon"/>
            <label>Afternoon</label>
    <input type = "checkbox"
            name = "evening"/>
            <label>Evening</label><br>
    <label>What are your plans?</label> 
            <input type = "text"
             name = "plan"/><br>
    <button type = "submit">
     submit
    </button>
    </fieldset> 
    </form>
    HERE;
    // end 'value exists' if
    ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to replace the `<h2>` and `</h2>` tags with `<span>` and `</span>`. That'll place them as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test1-1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
echo '<p>';
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "userName")){
// the form exists, so work with it
$userName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "userName");
print "Hi $userName";
}

if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "morning")){
    filter_input(INPUT_POST, "morning");
    print"how are you doing this morning?";
}
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "afternoon")){
    print"how are you doing this afternoon?";
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, "afternoon");
}
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "evening")){
    print"how are you doing this evening?";
    filter_input(INPUT_POST, "evening");
}
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "plan")){
    $plan = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "plan");
    print "Hope you have a wonderful time $plan";
}
echo '</p>';
//there's no input. Create the form 
print <<< HERE

<form action ="" method = "post">
<fieldset>
<label>Please enter your name</label> 
<input type = "text"
         name = "userName"/><br>
<label>Time of Day</label>
<input type = "checkbox"
        name = "morning"/>
        <label>Morning</label>
<input type = "checkbox"
        name = "afternoon"/>
        <label>Afternoon</label>
<input type = "checkbox"
        name = "evening"/>
        <label>Evening</label><br>
<label>What are your plans?</label> 
        <input type = "text"
         name = "plan"/><br>
<button type = "submit">
 submit
</button>
</fieldset> 
</form>
HERE;
// end 'value exists' if
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the different parts are showing up on different lines is that you have enclosed them in `<h2>` tags.

HTML heading elements (such as `<h2>`) are block-level elements. [Here is a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) to some documentation for a better explanation of exactly what that means, but in short (quoting from the linked document):

> Browsers typically display the block-level element with a newline both before and after the element.

In order to avoid this, you can either simply remove the `<h2>` tags, or replace them with an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) such as `<span>`.